# Select top 1 column along with CSV column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a table as below:

```
TableId       SId          Data        DataOwner 
1             10           aaaa        1001
2             10           aaaa        1000 
3             20           bbbb        1000 
4             10           ccc         2000
```

```sql
Declare @table1 table(TableId int, SId int, Data varchar(200), DataOwner int)
insert into @table1 values(1, 10, 'aaaa', 1001)
                           ,(2, 10, 'aaaa', 1000)
                           ,(3, 20, 'bbbb', 1000)
                           ,(4, 10, 'ccc', 2000)
```

When data is same for SId column then select dataowner values in comma seperated in ascending order and take any one of the TableId

```
TableId       SId         Data          DataOwner 
1             10           aaaa          1000, 1001 
3             20           bbbb         1000 
4                 10           ccc             2000
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly? What about your attempts didn't work? What *were* your attempts?

Comment: It's confusing because the name of the column is [data].  Naming columns with system reserved words is not a good habit to get into

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select
  min(TableId) TableId, [SId], [Data], string_agg(DataOwner, ',') within group (order by DataOwner) DataOwner
from @table1
group by [SID], [Data];
```

Results

```
TableId SId Data    DataOwner
1       10  aaaa    1000,1001
3       20  bbbb    1000
4       10  ccc     2000
```

Comment: This OP's first row has `1` not `2` for `TableID`. `MIN` would a safe assumption for that column, but both `MIN` and `MAX` could easily not return the correct value for `SId` and `Data`.

Comment: The OP wrote: "take any one of the TableId" so I picked MAX.  You're probably right anyway tho so I'll update.  Data is GROUP BY.  SID was not specified so I'll add to GROUP BY

Comment: My point, however, is you aren't going to pick an arbitrary row, but the highest values for each column from all the rows in the group; which itself could not be representative of a real "row".